# Drop columns in a pandas dataframe based on the % of null values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with around 60 columns and 2 million rows. Some of the columns are mostly empty. 
I calculated the % of null values in each column using this function.

```
def missing_values_table(df): 
    mis_val = df.isnull().sum()
    mis_val_percent = 100 * df.isnull().sum()/len(df)
    mis_val_table = pd.concat([mis_val, mis_val_percent], axis=1)
    mis_val_table_ren_columns = mis_val_table.rename(
    columns = {0 : 'Missing Values', 1 : '% of Total Values'})
    return mis_val_table_ren_columns
```

Now I want to drop the columns that have more than 80%(for example) values missing. I tried the following code but it does not seem to be working.

```
df = df.drop(df.columns[df.apply(lambda col: col.isnull().sum()/len(df) > 0.80)], axis=1)
```

Thank you in advance. Hope I'm not missing something very basic

I receive this error

> TypeError: ("'generator' object is not callable", u'occurred at index
>   Unique_Key')

Comment: Just to make sure this isn't the issue, when you say it's not working, did you you do `df = df.drop(...)`? Because dropping columns doesn't happen in place. The original dataframe is still the same, it just returns a new dataframe with some columns dropped.

Comment: I had forgotten to include the error. Sorry. I did try df=df.drop(..)

Comment: Unique_Key is the first column in the df

Comment: Could you post (a subset of) your dataframe? If your real data is sensitive, could you just make a dummy dataframe that looks similar to it? It need only have a few rows, just to make sure that in trying to answer your question, there isn't some part we're missing.

Answer (score 34):

You can use dropna() with threshold parameter

```
thresh = len(df) * .2
df.dropna(thresh = thresh, axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

Comment: That was a simple and elegant tweak

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
def missing_values(df, percentage):

    columns = df.columns
    percent_missing = df.isnull().sum() * 100 / len(df)
    missing_value_df = pd.DataFrame({'column_name': columns,
                                 'percent_missing': percent_missing})

    missing_drop = list(missing_value_df[missing_value_df.percent_missing>percentage].column_name)
    df = df.drop(missing_drop, axis=1)
    return df
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Answers should have at least a little bit of exposition even when the bulk of the answer needs to be code. Please edit your answer to include a brief explanation about how you think the code solves the problem presented in OPs question.